# How to print a new array from existing array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I need to create a new array of objects from the existing array on vuejs.

example first array :

```
import { ref } from 'vue';

const base_array = ref([
  {id: 1, name: Pill, timing: [morning, noon, evening, night]},
  {id: 2, name: Tablet, timing: [morning, evening]},
])
```

expected result :

```
const modified_array = ref([
  {id: 1, name: Pill, timing: [morning]},
  {id: 2, name: Pill, timing: [noon]},
  {id: 3, name: Pill, timing: [evening]},
  {id: 4, name: Pill, timing: [night]},
  {id: 5, name: Tablet, timing: [morning]},
  {id: 6, name: Tablet, timing: [evening]},
])
```

I've tried forEach and looping the array, but seems can't find the right function.
Thank youu

Comment: did you want `modified_array` to change when `base_array` changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work

```
const modified_array = ref(
    base_array.value.flatMap(({timing, ...r}) =>
        timing.map(timing => ({...r, timing:[timing]}))
    )
);
```

However, if you want `modified_array` to be reactive to changes in `base_array` - you'd want to use `computed` not `ref` for `modified_array` as in the code snippet below

If you watch, then the modified_array output changes when the base_array changes after three seconds with this code

```
setTimeout(() => base_array.value[1].timing.push('reactive!!!'), 3000);
```

Anyway, here's the example of fully functional code for vue3

```js
const { ref, createApp, computed } = Vue;


createApp({
    setup() {
        const base_array = ref([
          {id: 1, name: 'Pill', timing: ['morning', 'noon', 'evening', 'night']},
          {id: 2, name: 'Tablet', timing: ['morning', 'evening']},
        ]);
        const modified_array = computed(() =>
            base_array.value.flatMap(({ timing, ...r }) =>
                timing.map((t) => ({ ...r, timing: [t] }))
            )
        );
        setTimeout(() => base_array.value[1].timing.push('reactive!!!'), 3000);
        return { base_array, modified_array};
    }
    
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 0 !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="({id, name}) in base_array" :key="id">
    {{ id }}: {{ name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="({id, name, timing}, i) in modified_array" :key="i">
    {{ id }}: {{ name }} {{timing[0]}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `flatMap`, something like this:

```
const base_array = ref([
      { id: 1, name: Pill, timing: [morning, noon, evening, night] },
      { id: 2, name: Tablet, timing: [morning, evening] },
    ]);

const modified_array  = ref(base_array.value.flatMap(el => el.timing.map(t => ({id: el.id, name: el.name, timing: [t]}))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that by using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) along with the [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const base_array = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Pill', timing: ['morning', 'noon', 'evening', 'night']},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tablet', timing: ['morning', 'evening']},
];

let modified_arr = [];
let index = 1;

base_array.forEach(obj => {
    const {id, name, timing} = obj;
  timing.forEach(t => {
    modified_arr.push({ id: index, name, timing: [t]})
    index++;
  })
});

console.log(modified_arr);
```